# Stack level too deep when assigning association directly in model. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

```
class Campaign
  include MongoMapper::Document
  before_save :set_relationship

  key :name,                  String
  has_many :brokers

  timestamps!

  private
  def set_relationships
    broker = Broker.first
    self.brokers << broker
  end
```

Broker model is pretty much blank other than `has_many :campaigns`

It seems that assigning the relationship `before_save` causes an infinite loop. **Why is this happening? Are these relationships need to be set in the controller?**

The reason I want to do this - a user is allowed to input a list of bogus usernames, but only ones corresponding to real users must be associated with the `Campaign` model. I could iterate through the list and create the relationships there but that doesn't seem like controller work.

Comment: You need to define the relationships as `has_and_belongs_to_many` becazuse right now a `campaign has_many :brokers` and a `broker has_many :campaigns` both these relationships need to change to function appropriately. [Mongoid::Relationships](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/relations.html)

Answer (score 0):

The self.brokers << broker line triggers the before_save :set_relationship, because it already calls save there.
So you have an endless recursion.

You could add an :if parameter to the before_save and check if you have added it already.